# JQuery Autocomplete with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to write a JQuery autocomplete script which will call a url via AJAX and update autocomplete results as user enters data into the form.

I have my AJAX setup and currently returning JSON. But I don't know how to go about getting the autocomplete function to call it and use the response. I have managed to get the following working, but this is static data, so no good for my task:

```
$("input#name").autocomplete({
        source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"]
});
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote

```
    $( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
        source: "search.php",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ?
                "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
        }
    });
```

The php needs to return values in Json format like this
http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/search.php?term=ai

Json instructions https://www.php.net/json

Comment: I have my JSON formatted like this which is correct: [{"name":"Thomas","id":1}] how does it workout to put the ?term=ai on the end? Is there a way I can debug the response too?

Comment: Using php you do $_GET["term"] to get the querystring, then you do a database query and the results you serialize in Json. Here is an example. http://fromvega.com/wordpress/2007/05/05/auto-complete-field-with-jquery-json-php/

Comment: I'm getting somewhere now... can see bullet points appearing but no text for the suggestions.